# Compare relationship of two folder

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, mfc

**SCENARIO**

**PROCEDURE A** gathers files from a webservice, and copies them to a root folder. Sometimes files are copied in a subfolder of the root, for example:

```
c:\root\file1
c:\root\file2
c:\root\filea
c:\root\<unique random name>\fileA
```

I suspect (but I'm not sure) that the webservice runs on linux-system and file names are case-sensitive. So, files are copied on a Windows file-system, and when uppercase/lowercase conflicts occure, files are copied in a subfolder. The subfolder has an unique randomly generated name.

**PROCEDURE B** scans files in the *root* and sub-folders in order to archive them. Files correctly archived are deleted. **PROCEDURE A** and **PROCEDURE B** don't run simultaneously.

And now my task ... I've to delete empty subfolder of the root.

**FIRST SOLUTION (the easiest one)**

When procedure B ends, I can scan empty subfolders of the root, end then delete them. Well ...

```
DWORD DeleteEmptySubFolder(LPCSTR szRootFolder)
{
    DWORD dwError = 0;

    CString sFolder(szRootFolder);
    sFolder += "*.*";

    CFileFind find_folder;
    BOOL bWorking = find_folder.FindFile(sFolder);
    while (bWorking)
    {
        bWorking = find_folder.FindNextFile();
        if(find_folder.IsDots())
            continue;

        if(find_folder.IsDirectory())
        {
            if(PathIsDirectoryEmpty(find_folder.GetFilePath()))
            if(!RemoveDirectory(find_folder.GetFilePath()))
                dwError = GetLastError();
        }
    }

    return dwError;
}
```

and now here are the problems: I haven't got any control on **PROCEDURE B** and I don't know when it ends. **PROCEDURE B** can call a user function after archiving each individual file.

**SECOND SOLUTION (adequate but not too efficient)**

I can still call the above function

```
DWORD DeleteEmptySubFolder(LPCSTR szRootFolder)
```

It's not efficient for sure, it will scan all subfolders of the root for each archived file, but it will delete only empty subfolders.

**THIRD SOLUTION (it should work)**

When procedure B call user function, I know the root folder and the full path of the archived file. So I can check if the folder of the file is a sub-folder of the root:

```
#define EQUAL_FOLDER        0
#define A_SUBFOLDER_OF_B    1
#define B_SUBFOLDER_OF_A    2
#define UNRELATED_FOLDER    3
int CompareFolderHiearachy(LPCSTR szFolderA, LPCSTR szFolderB)
{
    if(_stricmp(szFolderA, szFolderB))
    {
        // StrStrI - Windows function (from shlwapi.dll) which finds the first occurrence of a substring within a string (the comparison is not case-sensitive).
        if(StrStrI(szFolderA, szFolderB) == szFolderA)
            return A_SUBFOLDER_OF_B;
        else if(StrStrI(szFolderB, szFolderA) == szFolderB)
            return B_SUBFOLDER_OF_A;
        else
            return UNRELATED_FOLDER;
    }
    else
        return EQUAL_FOLDER;
}
```

Maybe this solution could work fine in my scenario, but it can only handle cases where folder/file names are consistent. For example:

local disk:

```
root: C:\folder\
filename: c:\folder\subfolder\fileA
```

mapped disk:

```
root: Z:\folder\
filename: Z:\folder\subfolder\fileA
```

UNC:

```
root: \\SERVER\folder\
filename: \\SERVER\folder\subfolder\fileA
```

and now my *too generic* and *abstract* question, can I check the hierarchy/realtionship of two folders in the worst scenario ?

```
\\server\folder1\folder2 (UNC)
z:\folder2 (network drive).
```

or even worst ....

```
\\MYPC\folder1\folder2
c:\folder2
```

Maybe I'm asking a bit perverse question ... but it's quite challenging and intriguing, isn't it ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The step 1 to "attack" this problem is by visiting stackoverflow.com's [help], taking a [tour], and learning [ask] questions before posting your first question here. This way you will know what kind of questions are expected be asked on stackoverflow.com in order to get useful answers, instead of getting downvoted and closed as off-topic.

Comment: It's not possible (and you also need to conciser hardlinks and redirections).  This feels like an XY-problem ie why do you need to know the folder nesting?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but have a look at   https://superuser.com/questions/135752/list-mapped-network-drives-from-the-command-line-to-text-file

Comment: I think your problem is mainly focused on the third example. I tried to use MD5 to distinguish this point, because folders do not have MD5, so I compared the contents of folders to determine whether the network shared folder is the same as the local folder. But I also found a problem, that is, if I have two identical folders on my PC, the contents of the folders are copied, so MD5 is the same, and both folders are shared, then how can we distinguish which folder is?

Comment: Later, I read a document. By typing NET SHARE in cmd.exe, we can see the network address of the local shared folder. We can convert the address of the network folder to the local address by this method, so that your third example can be changed into the first two examples. So that it will be easy for u to solve this issue.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for your suggestion (and sarcasm), I really appreciate it. I'll do better next time.

Comment: @RichardCrittenYes, I think could be an XY-problem, I'm trying to find a super-solution for a too abstract and too general problem. I'm going to reconsider the whole problem, and then I'll re-edit the question. Thank you.

Comment: @SuarezZhou-MSFT thank you for your suggestions ... they're quite challenging.

Comment: system("net share >> D:\\1.txt"); Try this command, this will export the CMD content to the .txt file(D:\\1.txt). The shared folder will correspond to the local folder one by one. In your case, you can compare "\\server\folder1" with the content of the .txt file, and then replace it with the address of the local folder. Finally, you can get the local address, such as "C:\folder1\folder2". It's a lot of work and difficult to do so.

Comment: ok, I've just completely rewritten the question. I hope you enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

I improved the thrid solution; it can solve severale situations, but nfortunately it can't handle all the possible cases.

```
#define ERROR_OCCURED       -1
#define EQUAL_FOLDER        0
#define A_SUBFOLDER_OF_B    1
#define B_SUBFOLDER_OF_A    2
#define UNRELATED_FOLDER    3
int CompareFolderHiearachy(LPCSTR szFolderA, LPCSTR szFolderB)
{
    char pBuffer[32767];
    DWORD dwBufferLength = 32767;

    UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO * unameinfo = reinterpret_cast< UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO *>(pBuffer);

    DWORD dwRetVal = WNetGetUniversalName(szFolderA, UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(pBuffer), &dwBufferLength);
    if(dwRetVal != NO_ERROR && dwRetVal != ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED && dwRetVal != ERROR_BAD_DEVICE)
        return ERROR_OCCURED;

    CString sFolderA(unameinfo->lpUniversalName ? unameinfo->lpUniversalName : szFolderA);

    ZeroMemory(pBuffer, dwBufferLength);

    dwRetVal = WNetGetUniversalName(szFolderB, UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(pBuffer), &dwBufferLength);
    if(dwRetVal != NO_ERROR && dwRetVal != ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED && dwRetVal != ERROR_BAD_DEVICE)
        return ERROR_OCCURED;

    CString sFolderB(unameinfo->lpUniversalName ? unameinfo->lpUniversalName : szFolderB);

    if(_stricmp(sFolderA, sFolderB))
    {
        // StrStrI - Windows function (from shlwapi.dll) which finds the first occurrence of a substring within a string (the comparison is not case-sensitive).
        if(StrStrI(sFolderA, sFolderB) == static_cast<LPCSTR>(sFolderA))
            return A_SUBFOLDER_OF_B;
        else if(StrStrI(szFolderB, sFolderA) == static_cast<LPCSTR>(sFolderB))
            return B_SUBFOLDER_OF_A;
        else
            return UNRELATED_FOLDER;
    }
    else
        return EQUAL_FOLDER;
}
```

It can't solve the following:

```
folder A: \\MY_PC\shared_folder\folderA
folder B: C:\shared_folder
(\\MY_PC\shared_folder and C:\shared_folder are the sane folder)
```

and:

```
folder A: \\SERVER\shared_folderA\shared_folderB
folder B: \\SERVER\shared_folderB
```